# Rsa decryption with private key on PHP failed

Tags: php, rsa

hi i am getting error while decrypting RSA with private key above PHP, please help
(I try decrypt on c# private key works fine)

**Error**

```
error:04065072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed
```

**PHP**

```
  class RSA{
    protected $private;
   public function __construct()
{

 $this->private = @file_get_contents("private.pem");
}
    public function decrypt($data)
{
    if (is_null($data) || empty($data) || is_string($data) === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Needless to encrypt.');
    } elseif (is_null($this->private) || empty($this->private)) {
        throw new RuntimeException('You need to set the private key.');
    }
        $key = openssl_get_privatekey($this->private);
        if (!openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($data), $result, $key)){
             throw new Exception(openssl_error_string());
        }
        return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Seperate this ouy into a Question and an Answer. Then people will know where to look for the Answer

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem, I don't know why, it must be because my encoded string has invalid characters so when I send GET or POST it fails so my solution is to use toHex function () to encode data in Hex form and send it, and when receiving the data, use toStr() to decode it back.

```
public function toHex($string){
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}
return $hex;
 }


public function toStr($hex){
$string='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
    $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
}
return $string;
}
```

**C#**

```
public static string ToHex(string str)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        foreach (var t in bytes)
        {
            sb.Append(t.ToString("X2"));
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static string FromHexString(string hexString)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
```

**private key decrypt edit**

```
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($this->toStr($data)), $result, $key)
```

Comment: *send it* ... from what? To where?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk here I am using send from c# client to PHP server

Comment: But your `toHex()` function is written in php!

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk You can review the answer that I edit and added the c# code